# Fetching data from cloud firestore with latest data

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on react project. it's a blog website and I'm fetching data from the Firestore. I want to make popular posts sections, most commented posts and latest posts section. How can I do this? I mean what is a good way to do it? Do I compare for dates? if yes, then how?
I thought I will get the data according to dates in descending order, with this I can get the latest dates first. but again is it the right way to do this? Please help. thanx in advance :)

Comment: try adding `id's` to them all while creation time only, then sort them decreasing order, simple logic

Comment: In the case of Firestore, the id's it generates is in string format and I can't compare them. instead, I have a timestamp that I can compare to the latest one. But I don't know if it is right to compare timestamps

Comment: yes, you can do arithmetic operations on `timestamp`, its good and accurate

Comment: Thanx so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to model your data to have the following properties: 
 - `views`
 - `comments`
 - `publishedOn`

```
{
    name: string,
    content: String,
    views: Number,
    comments: [
        {
            userName: String,
            commentTitle: String,
            commentContent: String,
            commentedOn: Date
        }
    ],
    publishedOn: Date
}
```

The `views` property can hold an initial value maybe 0 and increment each time someone visit a particular blog post. You can then use the `views` property to check the blog post that has more views and display them in the `popular posts section` like this `blogPosts.orderBy("views", "desc").limit(3)`. Check out the [their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

For the most commented blog posts, simply check the number of comments on each of the blog posts, then order them as well.

For the latest posts, you can pull the latest posts by running something similar to

`blogPosts.orderBy("publishedOn", "desc").limit(3)`.

Hope this helps.